# Swift 4 SVProgressHUD not showing on load

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I have installed cooapods and SVProgressHub. I am unable to figure out how to show the SVProgressHUB loading screen.

`SVProgressHUD.show()`

This is inside my view controller.
I am new to swift and stack overflow. Cheers!

Comment: Where are you calling it from? Since you're new SO, you should take a minute to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Popssibly Try this:

```
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultStyle(.custom)
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.custom)
SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.red)           //Ring Color
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.yellow)        //HUD Color
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundLayerColor(UIColor.green)    //Background Color
SVProgressHUD.show()
```

**The output:**

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you are asking, are you looking to call SVProgressHUD during the splash screen ? or when the first view controller is opening.

If there is nothing being processed between when you call .show and when you call .dismiss, it simply might not be seen, even though you are making the calls.

In AppDelegate  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you can place some defaults

```
    SVProgressHUD.setBorderColor(kBrandBlue)
    SVProgressHUD.setBorderWidth(1.0)
    SVProgressHUD.setCornerRadius(44.0)
    SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(.blue)
    SVProgressHUD.setRingThickness(4.0)
    SVProgressHUD.setGraceTimeInterval(0.5)
```

I'm not sure what the default grace timer is, but you might want to check that.

If you call .show and dont call .dismiss, then it will keep spinning forever, so just put the .show in viewDidLoad for your ViewController and see if it comes up.

Hope that helps